# File.WriteAllText() runs OK, or does it?

Tags: c#, file-io

I've been starting at this code for the best part of 2 hours (literally) but I can not seem to grasp why this would fail. This method below does not report any exceptions, yet it seems to return false:

```
public bool SaveFile(string filename, object source)
{
    bool result = true;
    StringBuilder exportText = new StringBuilder(source.ToString());
    try {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, exportText.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        OnPluginError(new ErrorEventArgs(e));
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is: the file is properly written at the requested path, is complete, and readable. No exceptions are thrown, because the OnPluginError() handler invocation method isn't called - any message would be logged in that case, but there is nothing logged. It can't be a permission problem because the file does exist after the call.
And still, the method result is false.

The problem only appears in a Release build. In Debug builds, all seems to work OK. Hence, I can't use the debugger to step through.

This is called from a web application. Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have to guess? Either debug or add logging output

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in the debugger?

Comment: Attach a debugger and set a breakpoint in the catch block. The only explanation is that it enters the catch block and that your event handler does not log for some other reason.

Comment: Come on... is this a riddle? :P if it returns false it must be catching the exception. What about attaching a debugger and see what'e' is? or remove the catch all together and let it blow...

Comment: No, no riddle. I'm baffled at why this would happen. Remove the catch, but it didn't blow.And for the record, I have about 30 years of programming experience, so I know how to debug.

Comment: What is `source` and what should `source.ToString()` return?

Comment: No, I'm sure the handler works. The process this method is called from  uses that same handler to log messages too. And those messages are shown. So I'm pretty sure the handler works as expected....and that would mean the catch isn't executed.

Comment: give me the exact same parameters you use. If I get that thing to return false without entering the catch block, I will buy you a beer!

Comment: 'source' refers to an XDocument instance. 'source.ToString()' returns the XML as expected; the output file contains the complete XML.

Comment: What does the code look like that's calling this?  Where you are making the determination that it's returning false?

Comment: I would start looking at the internals of the OnPluginError() method for problems. Unless .NET is broken, it's likely that it's causing the confusion by not logging your error.

Comment: OT: You (really) don't need the StringBuilder. Just write source.ToString() directly.

Comment: For sanity's sake (mainly to check that the correct assembly is being bound to, and so you can verify this isn't occurring at the caller), add a `File.WriteAllText(somewhere, "result is " + result)` right after `result = false` in the catch block, then read the contents of the file at the path `somewhere`.

Comment: Put a `throw` after `result = false` and see what you get.  Perhaps `OnPluginError` is silently eating some exceptions.

Comment: You could also turn on tracing and add lots of writes to trace of the result variable to see at what line in the code it gets changed.  Tracing can be enabled in release.

Comment: @AaronLS: the result is stored in an auto-property, which is queried right after the call to SaveFile(). The property is false, because other code inside the if() isn't executed.

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary troubleshooting step, add another try catch to block any exceptions and then see if the function is still returning false.

```
public bool SaveFile(string filename, object source)
{
    bool result = true;
    StringBuilder exportText = new StringBuilder(source.ToString());
    try {
       try {
        File.WriteAllText(filename, exportText.ToString());
       } catch(Exception e) {  }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        OnPluginError(new ErrorEventArgs(e));
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

If it is returning true, then you have isolated the problem and determined that an exception is being thrown, causing the block with result = false to be run.

If it is still returning false, then you can be certain the problem is outside of this function, as the rules of control flow would dictate that the result variable would never be changed.

One possibility is you have an issue with either the code you think is being run is not really being run.  For example some issue with the build process not picking up your most recent code changes or redirection.  Checking the versions of the website project DLLs, doing clean/rebuild, adding additoinal code to write out trace messages, are all things you should try to cross check to verify your most recent code is being run.

Another possibility is a problem in the code that is checking the return value.

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow, and let you know what happened.

Comment: Alas, no good. I even turned on all exceptions are thrown, no matter what (Debug/Exceptions, checked all Thrown). But no exceptions were raised.

Answer (score 1):

Well...I do feel a bit silly here. I finally found the problem, and it is (as some posters questioned) not related to the `WriteAllText()` method at all.

FYI: this code ran deep inside an extensive plugin library. Not all that code was designed and written by me, and has been around for almost 2 years without running into problems.

As I mentioned, the `WriteAllText()` ran fine. It did. Problem was that the location of the file saved, was stored in a Dictionary, which in turn was requested from the plugin currently running. That Dictionary (containing plugin settings) turned out to be created from scratch with each call to that property! So I could add to it as much as I wanted....at the next call to that property, the newly added items would 'disappear' magically since the Dictionary was created anew.
Since it never surfaced before, and that code ran in a lot of other plugins with no problems, I didn't check that property. My bad.

Apologies to everyone that responded for wasting their time. Rest assured it won't happen any time soon! Lesson learned...